# Collision bug with cocos2d and tilemap

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

So I am making a simple cocos2d platformer and I am running into something a bit weird with collision. I have it so when jumping and hitting a block above you it stops the updward force and you begin falling. However the left and right sides of the block register much different. I have made the hit detection large on both sides to test what was going on. The right side of the block always works fine and responds to an increase. However the left side never responds to an increase. This may sound confusing so if you still aren't sure what I mean I can just post a quick youtube video on it and link it here.

Here is the code I am using:

```
-(CGPoint) tileCoorForPosition: (CGPoint)position{

    int x = floor((position.x + tilesMoved) / 40);
    int y = floor((((self.tileMap.mapSize.height * 40) - position.y) / 40));

    return ccp(x,y);
}
-(CGPoint) positionForTileCoord:(CGPoint) position{
    int x = position.x * 40 - tilesMoved;
    int y = (((self.tileMap.mapSize.height - position.y - tilesMovedUp)* 40));
    return ccp(x,y);
}

 CGPoint tl_playerPosition = [self tileCoorForPosition:ccp(self.character.position.x - self.character.contentSize.width/2, self.character.position.y + self.character.contentSize.height*2)];
 CGPoint tr_playerPosition = [self tileCoorForPosition:ccp(self.character.position.x + self.character.contentSize.width/2, self.character.position.y + self.character.contentSize.height*2)];

if(tr_GID || tr_GID || tm_GID || tml_GID || tmr_GID)
    {
        jumpForce = -1;
        jumpForce += gravity;

    }
```

Comment: if(tr_GID || tr_GID || ....     hmmm ! really ?

Comment: Oh....I've been staring at that for a very long time and failed to notice that....Thanks man!

Comment: Shiva says : "The uninformed innocent bystander will recognize it in a flash" ... hope that was it, cuz i sure dont know what these iVars mean :)